# The SyncStatus API for QuickBooks Desktop Never Shows any Results for Added SalesTax Items

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I have added SalesTax items through the Quickbooks IPP API for Quickbooks Desktop and I can see they have made it to the Desktop Company file. Yet a Query of the SyncStatus API always produces nil.

My example SyncRequest looks like the following:

```
<SyncStatusRequest xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/xmlrequest ./RestDataFilter.xsd"><OfferingId>ipp</OfferingId><NgIdSet><NgId>740131</NgId><NgObjectType>SalesTax</NgObjectType></NgIdSet></SyncStatusRequest>
```

Answer (score 1):

SalesTax Item Create operation is not supported at production quality. It's at beta only. https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0500_quickbooks_windows/0500_supported_objects

hence the reason you are not getting the status in the Sync API.

thanks
jarred